# Nagios - Hipchat integration through Hipsaint

Tags: python, nagios, hipchat

We are trying to integrate nagios (4.1.1) notifications with Hipchat using Hipsaint. We followed the instructions posted [here](https://github.com/hannseman/hipsaint) (keep in mind that the instructions mention nagios 3). We filled in the Token and Room_ID. We get the following output:

```
:~# hipsaint --token=XXXXXXXXXX --room=XXXXXXX --type=host --inputs="$HOSTNAME$|$LONGDATETIME$|$NOTIFICATIONTYPE$|$HOSTADDRESS$|$HOSTSTATE$|$HOSTOUTPUT$" -n

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/hipsaint", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/hipsaint/bin/commands.py", line 78, in main
    msg.deliver_payload()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/hipsaint/messages.py", line 68, in deliver_payload_v1
    raw_response = urlopen(self.urlv1, message_params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 133, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 416, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 529, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 454, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 388, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 537, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized
```

We also tried the following:

> Using a new Token
>
> Updating Python from ver 2.7 to 3
>
> Opening the ports for hipchat on the nagios Security Group

Any idea how we can proceed?

Comment: did u fill out user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test the validity of your auth token and make sure the test is not responding with "*401 Unauthorized*" status.
If you're using your own private HipChat Server, replace `api.hipchat.com` with your HipChat Server hostname.
Replace `YOUR_TOKEN` with the auth token you generated.  Execute the following from your Nagios server:

```
curl https://api.hipchat.com/v1/rooms/list?auth_token=YOUR_TOKEN&auth_test=true
```

Source:  https://www.hipchat.com/docs/api/auth

Comment: Thanks for the reply. We were creating the tokens from room level. We created a new token from here: https://www.hipchat.com/admin/api  and  notifications are working now.